# Python Mechanize: how to select a dropdown list when two have the same name in web page?

Tags: python, mechanize

The html that I'm trying to make mechanize parse is:

```
<select id="topic_id2" name="topics[]" title="blabla" tabindex="4" class="createSelect">
here go options
```

But then right below it there is another dropdown, with the following code:

```
<select id="topic_id3" name="topics[]" title="optional" tabindex="5" class="createSelect">
```

Now if it helps at all, I need not select any value from the latter one, since it is optional.

When I try

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.select_form(name="form")
br["topics[]"] = ["Internet"]
```

I get:

```
mechanize._form.AmbiguityError: more than one control matching name 'topics[]'
```

Is there a way I can select a control based on its id, using mechanize.Browser() (while retaining all the other form syntax)?

Thanks

Comment: You can access the controls by their index in the form, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482308/differentiating-between-html-form-select-items-with-the-same-name/6483458#6483458

Comment: can you +1 the answer in the link?

Answer (score 1):

The external documentation for `mechanize` is quite small and contains just a few examples, but the in-code documentation is far more extensive.

Not having tested this, with an `HTMLForm` instance called `form` you should be able to call `form.find_control(id="topic_id3")` and get what you want. I'm not sure how to do this with just a `Browser` object, but have you tried `br.find_control(id="topic_id3")`?